# How to convert Collection of array of arrays to Eloquent style Collection of Objects of Objects in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, collections

I'm pulling data from Airtable, which returns like so:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#496 ▼
  #items: array:11 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => "rec4CaAx5EwGGi0I3"
      "fields" => array:8 [▼
        "description" => "Soft covers for switches"
        "price" => 7
        "tags" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "recvPyxXM6GdIjgEr"
          1 => "recvskfZPFMRPXzEb"
        ]
```

I can find how to convert to:

Collection of Objects of arrays, or even

Collection of Collections of Collections using recursive methods,

*but not*

Collection of Objects of Objects (of Objects)

so I can access the data like `$data->fields->name` like I can with normal Eloquent fetched results

Comment: please check this if it helps you click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488623/how-can-i-convert-array-two-dimensional-to-collection-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I can use json encode / decode to convert it all to objects and then collect it@

```
    $things = Airtable::table('things')->all();

    $things = json_decode(json_encode($things),FALSE);
    
    $things = collect($things);
```